# RSpec request object is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to test for cookies in my request spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Cookies"
  it "should set correctly" do
    request.cookies['foo'] = 'bar'
  end
end
```

But this gives me `undefined method 'cookies' for nil:NilClass`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `request` object will be nil inside your test case until you make an http request using one of the methods `get`, `post`, `delete`, `put`, etc.

For example, your code would work if you had preceded `request.cookies['foo'] = 'bar'` with `get root_path`.

Comment: What if I want to set the `request.env['HTTPS']` header *before* making the request?

Comment: For https requests you can use the rspec `https!` helper before making the request.